# Remove busybox from buildroot

Tags: boot, busybox, init, buildroot, hardening

As part of Linux **hardening** we want to remove **busybox** from filesystem created with **buildroot**.

But I am not sure if system can boot without it.

I am quite sure that there are init files that depends on busybox.

**Is it possible to boot without busybox or does it require a custom init ?**

Comment: Is it for a bare metal system, a VM, or for a Docker container? busybox contains all the commands so it is not easy to remove.

Comment: Which distribution? Why have you not made a test in a VM yet,?

Comment: What kind of system is it? Why do you think that removing a program would harden your system?

Comment: It is for buildroot. I might have forgotten to mention it. I edited the question.

Answer (score 7):

It all depends on whether your distro uses Busybox for `init`.

To point you in the right direction, run `ls -l /sbin/init`.

If you get something like the following (example from OpenWRT):

```
~# ls -l /sbin/init
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         10824 Jan 31  2016 /sbin/init
```

It means `init` is a different application and you may be able to remove Busybox.  You'll still need to replace all the command `init` requires with alternatives as Busybox provides many tools required for booting successfully.

However, if you get (example from Alpine Linux):

```
~$ ls -l /sbin/init
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 May  3 04:49 /sbin/init -> /bin/busybox
```

It means `init` is provided by Busybox and you'll not be able to boot unless you can replace Busybox's `init` with an alternative.

You have to consider whether you are really hardening your system by doing this as you'll end up replacing one binary with many.

Comment: Even if `init` itself isn't the one from Busybox, if a system has Busybox, it probably has other critical programs provided by Busybox, for example `sh`.

Comment: @Gilles - edited and added as you commented :-)

Comment: Using this solution, does buildroot provide the option to entirely remove busybox from buildroot ?

Answer (score 3):

I routinely delete busybox in my master template/Debian VMs.

As for Debian, it is a matter of not allowing it to install both the `busybox` and `busybox-static`packages.

You just have to keep in mind the recovery/rescue options will be more limited in a system without it. e.g. I might keep it on a physical system, I delete it as a norm form VMs to save space and under the Unix old golden rule of keeping the minimum of software installed.

At least speaking for Debian, the uninstall makes the necessary modifications in the background, and it is neither necessary to do any extra steps nor customizing anything.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use buildroot (just edit the question). So this solution may not be relevant in my case.